# How to create a Vertical Strikethrough in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I can create this effect using tables and a background image, but would really like to be able to use CSS, please. Is it possible?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/2ARfR/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/arisuy/5/edit

Relevant CSS

```
p {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center; 
  position : relative;
}

p:before { 
  position: absolute;
  content : "";
  left  : 50%;
  top   : 0;
  height: 100%;
  width : 0;
  border-right: 1px #666 solid;

}
```

Comment: I've changed a bit the css... instead of giving width:50% I positioned the pseudoelement with left: 50%

Comment: would you please explain the difference?, I mean, does it really matter? would one or the other break on mobile devices, for example

Comment: no, it's just me :) it doesn't make any appreciable difference

Comment: Can this be applied to just a single span somehow instead of all spans or <p> tags?

Comment: @gtilflm use an unique class name for the element and change the css from `p` and `p:before` to `p.class-name` and `p.class-name:before`